# How to get date and time on which video is created using iphone?

Tags: iphone

i need to categorise video on the basis of date and time on which it is created.
I tried usin 
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset) {
                CLLocation *location = [myasset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];

in  (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

delegate but it reflects current date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code sample above, looks like you're trying to get your latitude and longitude.  :-)

To get the date and time of an ALAsset, simply do something like this;

```
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy 'at' HH:mm"];
    NSDate * dateFileCreated = [theAsset valueForProperty: @"ALAssetPropertyDate"];

    NSLog( @"date for this file is %@ %@", [[[theAsset defaultRepresentation] url] absoluteString], [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateFileCreated] );
    [dateFormatter release];
```

I put a date formatter in there so you can see the date in your console log, but in release code you probably do NOT want to allocate and release a formatter while enumerating ALAssets.

Hope this information helps you out!